# broken Internationalization through API

Tags: api, internationalization, foursquare

Some days ago I created a small PHP-Extension for mediawiki using php-foursquare library. To get the categories in german I added "Accept-Language: de" to the HTTP Header like described here https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning

At first everything worked as it should, but now I'm getting the results in englisch again. Is there any bug/issue about this?

Comment: Are you setting that "v" parameter like the URL specifies? (my apologies for posting this initially as an answer, not a comment)

Comment: The URL looks like this https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b6ca237f964a52027482ce3?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&v=20120228&locale=de
The point is, when gettig there with my browser, where my locale is also set to german, I get the categories in english too.

Comment: FWIW, that URL you provided isn't exactly right -- it should use an "oauth_token" parameter for auth instead of "client_id" and "client_secret". But that's probably not your issue. Can you tell us exact dates of the latest time you remember it working, and the earliest time you knew it was broken?

I'll talk to some of the engineers on this and see if anything might've broken recently.

And, FWIW, this works fine for me if I use the "locale=de" param.

Comment: but oauth only works for logged in users? Or am I missing something. For public data with no user authentication I need this cliend_id and client_secret? And why is the php-foursquare allow this request and it works, when it's not right?

It definetly worked about a week ago. And I think first time it was broken was on Saturday (07. July).

Comment: I made a short check with apigee and the locale param works correctly with oauth but not with the client_id client_secret method for request with no user authentication.

Comment: Can confirm this bug. `locale` URL parameter as well as `Accept-Language:` have no effect when userless access is used. This issue further seems to be API version independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed that this is a bug. I've reported it internally to the relevant team, hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: This has been fixed. Sorry for the long delay!